# Syntax for virtual functions

Tags: c++, syntax, polymorphism

While making a function virtual in c++ where do I have to write "virtual" keyword? Does it make a difference if I write virtual int function_name instead of int virtual function_name like in java

Comment: Why don't you check it? You think there is some hidden nit pick in the order of tokens? Or you just don't know if you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While making a function virtual in c++ where do I have to write `virtual` keyword?

In the function declaration, before the function name, and after any attribute specifiers, along with the other specifiers (including the type specifier for the function's return type).

The general syntax for a declaration is

```
simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq<opt> init-declarator-list<opt> ;
    attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq<opt> init-declarator-list ;
```

where both `virtual` (a *function-specifier*) and the return type (a *type-specifier*) are part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, and the name being declared is part of the *init-declarator-list*.

> Does it make a difference if I write `virtual int function_name` instead of `int virtual function_name`

No, the order of the specifiers makes no difference.

However, you might surprise some people if you put `virtual` after the type specifier, since it's more common to put it before. I didn't know you could do that until I answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to write `const int n; virtual void a(); volatile char s;` where `const, virtual and volatile` are modifiers.

It doesn't mean it will work better or it will be "more correct". As @MikeSeymour pointed out, it's an aesthetic choice.

Comment: Why would it be better? It seems to me to be purely an aesthetic choice.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I didn't say it'll _work_ better. You're right, it's an aesthetic choice, I'm gonna edit my answer. Thanks.